# Is it possible to record sound from one window?

Tags: c#, audio, record

I've managed to write program to record sound from Input Devices, but I'm more interested in recording from one window that plays some sounds. Is it possible to catch those sounds and not all possible sounds played currently?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to capture the audio output of a particular program with a different program that you are writing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture Sound Output In C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292076/capture-sound-output-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

As the program you want to record is talking directly to the sound driver api your only chance would be to create an own "man in the middle" sound driver which could filter off and forward an audio stream to your application.

So if you are not planning to invest a serious amount of time the answer probably is "No, its not possible".