# Capturing Window's audio in C#

Tags: c#, windows, audio

Is it possible to record Window's output sounds programmatically in C#? A bit like recording something from the "what you hear" or "stereo output" feature (without having to select them)?

Comment: I think this would be sound card specific.  I'm not 100% certain though.  Interesting question, does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292076/capture-sound-output-in-c

Comment: @drachenstern: your edit was *not* what the person was asking.

Comment: @MusiGenesis I wasn't sure one way or the other. It seemed to be the other way.

Comment: @musi No. We do smartgrid stuff, so to speak.

Comment: @Musi ~ I like it for now, check back with me in five years ;)

Comment: Interesting... @Musi do you ever use the chat feature here on the site?

Comment: @drach: no, I've said too much already. :)  If I suddenly disappear, will you tell my parents I loved them?

Comment: @Musi ~ lol, indeed sir.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called [loopback recording](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and it *is* possible in Windows.  If you have a soundcard that supports loopback (I just checked on my low-end Toshiba laptop, and it doesn't) you can record straight from the loopback device using the `waveInOpen` etc. API, which is easy to use in C#.  Note: recording audio in this way necessarily entails a reduction in quality, since the audio signal is converted to analog for output and then re-digitized to support the loopback interface.

If you don't have a soundcard, WASAPI will let you do this.  I suppose WASAPI can be used with C#, but it looks painful.

Comment: Is this the one? http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm/waveinopen.html?diff=y

Comment: http://winmm.codeplex.com/  is an excellent C# wrapper of the `winmm.dll` API functionality.

Comment: I should clarify my answer here by saying that the `waveInOpenEtc.` API is a royal $@&$!#& to use in C#, unless you find a good code sample that wraps it up for you, like the above.

Comment: There is a **working** example here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812224/c-sharp-recording-audio-from-soundcard

Comment: @MusiGenesis, Is there any way to capture the byte stream before it is converted to analogue?

Answer (score 6):

Also checkout the [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) library.

PS. C++ but relevant http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2008/12/16/sample-wasapi-loopback-capture-record-what-you-hear.aspx?PageIndex=2

Comment: In NAudio, there is a `WasapiCapture` class, that can be used for capturing using WASAPI loopback.

Comment: There has recently been added a `WasapiLoopbackCapture` class that simplifies this process.  As of Aug 2012 it is not included in the v1.5 release, I had to download the sources and compile to use it.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812224/c-sharp-recording-audio-from-soundcard for a **working** solution

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit tardy to the party, but [CSCore](https://github.com/filoe/cscore) has a pretty great library for managing windows audio events in C#.

This in particular looks like what you're wanting. http://filoe.github.io/cscore/sharpDox/1.2.0-release/#type/WasapiLoopbackCapture

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture audio output you can use **"WasapiLoopbackCapture"** https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/WasapiLoopbackCapture.md

If you want to capture audio input you can use **"RecordWavFileWaveIn"**
https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/RecordWavFileWinFormsWaveIn.md

Just install the reference package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio