# record system sound (stereomix) to a file

Tags: delphi, audio, system, record, wmp

iam trying to record sound from an activex WMP control playing an internet radio stream, and because no simple way to do it, i decided to record the system sound or the so called "what you hear" (the stereomix, which is disabled in many PCs).

so, how can i record system sound and save it an mp3, wav... file, without enabling stereomix, or how to enable it programatically, without user interaction.

i have no experience with audio applications, so please dont say try

1. BASS - www.un4seen.com
2. NewAC - symmetrica.net/newac/
3. WavePlayer - www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/waveplayer/

without giving me code exemple, cause i already tried to understand how to use, but, if i did i wouldnt askin you here.

i'am new here, and this is my first question
[i hope i get good answers]

THANKS IN ADVANCE :]

Comment: I would strongly advice not to record the stereomix in order to record from a radio stream, you loose quality, because you probably recompress the stream and you also record everything else (like Windows system sounds and sound from other running applications).

Comment: Another approach is to find out the stream URL and dump the stream using TCP.

Comment: If you go the "stereo mix" way note that not all sound drivers support this feature. I don't know if the new sound API introduced with Vista alleviate this issue. You could use a virtual sound card in this case (like `Virtual Audio Cable`).

Comment: Related (more general) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241352/is-it-possible-to-record-sound-played-on-the-sound-card

Comment: of course i have the stream url, i set the activex control to play it. so, regarding dumping using TCP, do you have any code exemple to start with ?

Comment: What kind of stream do you want to dump? It depends on the protocol that it's based on. There are tools out there that can probably help you like http://streamripper.sourceforge.net/ , VLC, mplayer or rtmpdump.

Comment: BTW: You know the legal ramification of writing a tool that records or dumps streams, right?

Comment: i do, the streams are local (Tunisian) internet radios. they even record their streams and share them on social sites, so it wont be a problem. protocols are http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we came up (in the question comments) with the conclusion that it might be better to record the radio stream instead of recording from the soundcard:

Have a look at `Indy`, `Synapse` or `ICS`. (Delphi comes with Indy out of the box)

There should be examples for each of these components that show how to read data from a `HTTP`/`TCP` server.

Be aware that the data is probably not just plain `MP3` or WMV, but there is usually some kind of *framing* that inserts title information and divides the sound data into chunks.

There are many streaming servers (i.e. `Shoutcast`, `Icecast` and others) out there that have different ways to encode the audio data.

You should first find out what kind of `streaming server` your internet radio is running. The first thing that happens when you send a `HTTP GET request` is usually a response that has some identification information.

You could also end up with just a playlist file that has the real URL inside.

PS: You might want to search for (or ask) additional questions on SO to get more information about the topics I mentioned.

Hope that helps.

Comment: THANK YOU @Jens, this don't really solve the problem, but at least i know where to start from. anyway, thanks again for the kind information. accepted :]