# Capture PC sound

Tags: c#, .net, audio

Using C#, i'm trying to capture the audio that the PC is playing, without using WASAPI and loopbacks, because it appears that my soundcard does not support it. How do programs like TeamViewer do it? As people can hear audio from my PC when I use that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing Window's audio in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953125/capturing-windows-audio-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The answers to that use loopbacks, which my sound card does not support.

Answer (score 4):

you could try to use the Expression Encoder SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=18974 I'm not completely sure if you are allowed to redistribute it and it might need to be installed on the target computer. But you can very easily use it to record Audio and Video from your Desktop:

```
        var j = new Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.ScreenCapture.ScreenCaptureJob();
        j.OutputScreenCaptureFileName = @"C:\Users\Dominik\Desktop\test.wmv";
        //j.AddAudioDeviceSource(Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices.EncoderDevices.FindDevices(Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices.EncoderDeviceType.Audio);
        var audioDevices = Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices.EncoderDevices.FindDevices(Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices.EncoderDeviceType.Audio);
        var videoDevices = Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices.EncoderDevices.FindDevices(Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices.EncoderDeviceType.Video);
        j.AddAudioDeviceSource(audioDevices.ElementAt(1));
        j.Start();
```

You need to add references to the .dll-files inside C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Expression\Encoder 4\SDK to use the Encoder SDK.