# Recording audio output from application

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, video, record

I'm currently building a project on C++ using Visual Studio on Windows 8. This application captures video from camera and triggers some virtual animations in real-time, with some sounds being played along with the animations.

The user has the option to record the experience in video and sound. I already am able to record video, now I want to create a audio track of the sounds that are being played by the application, to later fuse both video and audio files.

So, which is the best way to record audio output from an application in windows?
Let me stress that I do NOT want to record audio from any input devices (such as a microphone), only from the application itself.

Best regards.

Comment: There is a similar thing mentioned for C# with using WASAPI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953125/capturing-windows-audio-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

There is no recording of application output. If you generate audio on your own, you make a copy for the recording purposes, mix if you have multiple sources, and then use one of the APIs to produce a file depending on your preferences: directly writing a WAV file, Windows Media audio files (ASF/WMA), DriectShow, Media Foundation, third party libraries.

Real playback audio data is being mixed and sent for further playback. Sometimes you can enable loopback recording to capture fully mixed output (not just of specific application through) as if it is a capture from realtime audio input device.