# c# how to get real time desktop sound and process it

Tags: c#, audio, real-time

I am trying to get real-time desktop sound data to process it in c#
is it possible

I am trying to do it because I want to visualize the music

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capturing Window's audio in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953125/capturing-windows-audio-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.