# C# recording audio from soundcard

Tags: c#, audio, audio-recording, cscore

I want to record audio from my soundcard(output). I've found [CSCore on codeplex](http://cscore.codeplex.com/) but I could not find any examples. Does anyone know how to use the library to record audio from my soundcard and write the record data onto the harddrive? Or does anyone know a few tutorials on that library?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Take a look at the [CSCore.SoundIn namespace](http://cscore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CSCore/SoundIn/ISoundIn.cs). The [WasapiLoopbackCapture](http://cscore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CSCore/SoundIn/WasapiLoopbackCapture.cs) class is able to record directly from any output device. But keep in mind that [WasapiLoopbackCapture](http://cscore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CSCore/SoundIn/WasapiLoopbackCapture.cs) is only available since Windows Vista.

EDIT: This code should work for you.

```
using CSCore;
using CSCore.SoundIn;
using CSCore.Codecs.WAV;

...

using (WasapiCapture capture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture())
{
    //if nessesary, you can choose a device here
    //to do so, simply set the device property of the capture to any MMDevice
    //to choose a device, take a look at the sample here: http://cscore.codeplex.com/

    //initialize the selected device for recording
    capture.Initialize();

    //create a wavewriter to write the data to
    using (WaveWriter w = new WaveWriter("dump.wav", capture.WaveFormat))
    {
        //setup an eventhandler to receive the recorded data
        capture.DataAvailable += (s, e) =>
            {
                //save the recorded audio
                w.Write(e.Data, e.Offset, e.ByteCount);
            };

        //start recording
        capture.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();

        //stop recording
        capture.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: in this code, where the result audio file is stored ? I mean i did not understand the path in which sound is stored.

Comment: @abidinberkay, you can change `"dump.wav"` to `@"C:\Users\youruser\folder\filename.wav"`

Comment: Florian can i solve my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240612/how-transfer-system-mic-audio-stream-to-attached-device-mic-audio-stream?noredirect=1#comment63908020_38240612 using your answer.

Comment: I tried the above code on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017 and version 1.2.1.2 of CSCore, and got an exception of IAudioClient::Initialize caused an error: 0x800401fb, "Object is not registered" when I called capture.Initialize().  Is there some additional code I need here?

Comment: Why not working on Win10? DataAvailable not get called, wav file is empty.

Comment: Would it be possible to manually feed audios into microphone?