# CSCore library using in Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, audio, wave, cscore

Here:

[C# recording audio from soundcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812224/c-sharp-recording-audio-from-soundcard)

is example implementation using CSCore library, but it works only in console application.
Is it possible to use this in Windows Forms Application?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? What have you tried?

Comment: It is a *audio* library, it doesn't give a hoot about a user interface.  The only mistake you can make is not trying it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.

You have to split the code over two buttons, say `start` and `stop`.
The code before the `Console.ReadKey()` goes in the Click event of the `start` button and everything after the `Console.ReadKey()` goes in the click event of the `stop` button.

In the console variant all variables are local to the method. In the WinForms variant that will no longer work so we *promote* the local variables to the class level of the form.

The using statements are basically a try/catch/finally block with a call to Dispose in the finally block. The closing and disposing becomes now our own responsibility so in the `stop` the `Dispose`method of both the Writer and the Capture is called after which the class variables are assigned a null value.

You end up with something like this:

```
public class Form1:Form 
{
    // other stuff 

    private WasapiCapture capture = null;
    private WaveWriter w = null;

    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            capture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
            capture.Initialize();
            //create a wavewriter to write the data to
            w = new WaveWriter("dump.wav", capture.WaveFormat));
            //setup an eventhandler to receive the recorded data
            capture.DataAvailable += (s, capData) =>
            {
                //save the recorded audio
                w.Write(capData.Data, capData.Offset, capData.ByteCount);
            };
            //start recording
            capture.Start();     
    }

    private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (w != null && capture !=null)
        { 
            //stop recording
            capture.Stop();
            w.Dispose();
            w = null;
            capture.Dispose();
            capture = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code was adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18812248/578411) by user [thefiloe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1293906/thefiloe)