# How to capture audio stream in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, audio, audio-streaming, naudio

I ask this question because there is an internet radio I listen to very often. It looks like it streams using wowza server.  In Chrome's debug console's network tab, I can see urls like this:

http://rtmpbrk001.ddr.ly/live/show1/chunklist.m3u8?wowzasessionid=457131290

[Note: the URL above is  modified for this post, don't even try it.]

I can listen to this radio in the web browser at the radio's website.

However, I am very much interested in playing it in my Sonos speaker, which currently does not support the audio format of the said radio.

So, I'd like to create an asp.net web application to somehow capture the audio stream and convert the stream on the fly to mp3 for example, then I will be able to play it through Sonos.

I know that I can play it through my Sonos speaker via an airport express, but that's a different story and not what I am interested in doing.

My question is: Is my idea practical? If yes, what do I need to capture live audio stream in an asp.net application? Can Naudio help me?

Thanks a lot for not closing this question for reasons like "not constructive", coz I really would like to get this interesting idea going.

Comment: After some brain storming, I guess the only solution is to capture the audio signal that goes through the sound card and convert it on the fly and then stream it through my web server. Maybe use CSCore http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812224/c-sharp-recording-audio-from-soundcard

Comment: I am still researching this. And I found that another website streams this radio in aac format. However, it seems to be in chunks like so: http://1.2.3.4/channels/1/32410245-0.aac, http://1.2.3.4/channels/1/32410245-1.aac, http://1.2.3.4/channels/1/32410245-2.aac, ... http://1.2.3.4/channels/1/32410245-a.aac, http://1.2.3.4/channels/1/32410245-b.aac, ... http://1.2.3.4/channels/1/32410245-f.aac . And I can feed each of this url into windows media player, and it'll play that chunk.  So, another solution to the whole problem would be to capture all these requests and play them 1 by 1.