# How to pass computer audio to a program for visualization purposes?

Tags: c#, vb.net, audio, visualizer

Using Visual Basic, or C# - I would like to write an audio visualization program to use Fast Fourier transform - once I've got the audio stream, I can complete the program myself without help. However, I cannot find a way to input the entirety of the Windows computer's audio through the visualizer.

Does anyone know a way to do this, perhaps using the IAudioClient Interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812224/c-sharp-recording-audio-from-soundcard). It is using `CSCore`.  Maybe you can use this sample for getting your audio stream.

This library has also a inbuilt visualisation sample on its github repo -- please consider downloading and using it.

Comment: Thank you! Writing the code now, I'm going to keep this question open until I'm sure it works - otherwise, this is the answer!