# play audio in an embedded media player

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, windows-media-player

I have a client station that downloads .wav file and plays with the embedded medai player by using AxWindowsMediaPlayer library. I need to download the audio and give the url of the file to my media player. I was just wondering if there is any way that I don't store it in a physical storage, and load it from a memory for the media player. There would lots of audio control on the media player though.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Play audio from a stream using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184683/play-audio-from-a-stream-using-c)