# How can I play an MP3 from a memory stream in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, mp3

I'm trying to play an MP3 sound but I need it played from a memory stream (I don't have the actual file). What's my best option to do this? `mciSendString` accepts a file name as a parameter but not a memory stream. Is is possible to play the mp3 file with winmm's `PlaySound`?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this really a C-only question? If not, please include other tags.

Comment: Hi Ron. You should go back to your previous questions and mark the answer that helped you the most as the "accepted" answer. This will make people more motivated to help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play Audio from a Stream using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184683/play-audio-from-a-stream-using-c)

Answer (score 2):

For [Alvas.Audio](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx) see code below

```
//Memory stream with mp3 audio data
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Mp3Reader mr = new Mp3Reader(ms);
PlayerEx plex = new PlayerEx();
plex.OpenPlayer(mr.ReadFormat());
plex.AddData(mr.ReadData());
plex.StartPlay();
```