# How to parse MP3 files on Windows 2008R2?

Tags: .net, mp3, windows-server-2008

Does anyone know a good way for my .net app to decode MP3 files to PCM on Win2k8R2?

A few caveats:
  - it should run in a 64bit process (no WoW)
  - should be free or open source (no Bass.net)

Thanks

Comment: parse? do you mean to read the id3 tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) is what you need.

Comment: Would I have to use the DMO codec to be x64?  [NAudio NoDriver error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433191/naudio-nodriver-error-net)

Comment: It looks like you would. Mark Heath (who answered the linked question) is the guy who wrote NAudio, so he probably knows what he's talking about. :)

Comment: ok I tested that and it works, I'll mark your answer.  However it brings me to another question- is it possible to install the Windows Media COM object that the DMO version needs WITHOUT using the "Add Feature" in Server Manager?  I'll ask this separately.

Comment: You'll have to ask that separately, coz I dunno.

Comment: BTW You can use Windows Media MP3 Decoder directly as the DMO/MFT. DMO interface is simple enough and for simple things you can be fine with it, without NAudio on top. You can use Windows Media.NET to interface your managed code to Windows Media API components. NAudio still might be a good idea if you find the API a good fit to your needs.