# Speech recognition to text Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is possible to recognition speech to text in Windows Phone 8?

Is supported for all languages or only installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use the google api text to speech perfectly free on windows phone 8 and it works great:

you can find how to do it here:
[How can I use google text to speech api in windows form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243560/how-can-i-use-google-text-to-speech-api-in-windows-form)

of course this needs internet connection and  NAudio  which is open source!

google works the best for me

if you want an offline option you might be interested in:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483347/Speech-recognition-speech-to-text-text-to-speech-a

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380027/Csharp-Speech-to-Text

Comment: Thanks but internet connection is needed. I looking for offline option :)

Answer (score 2):

[Just use the services out of the box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207021%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
private async void ButtonSR_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // Create an instance of SpeechRecognizerUI.
  this.recoWithUI = new SpeechRecognizerUI();

  // Start recognition (load the dictation grammar by default).
  SpeechRecognitionUIResult recoResult = await recoWithUI.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

  // Do something with the recognition result.
  MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You said {0}.", recoResult.RecognitionResult.Text));
}
```