# How to play mp3 from a cryptoStream using NAudio?

Tags: .net, audio, encryption, mp3, naudio

I have an existing program that uses the .NET System.Media.SoundPlayer to play a wav file from a memory stream. The reason I need to do this is because the wav files are encrypted on the disk... I decrypt them to a memory stream and feed that stream to the player. It works fine.

But I'd rather use mp3's... they are smaller. I'm exploring NAudio as a solution, but can't figure out how to play an mp3 from the crypto stream.

The code I am currently using to play the encrypted wav file is this:

```
public void PlayEncMP3(String sourceFile)
{
    FileStream input = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("64BITKEY");
    cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("64BIT_IV");

    CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(input, cryptic.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    MainPlayer = new SoundPlayer(crStream);
    MainPlayer.Play();
}
```

This code works perfectly. It opens the encrypted wav file, decrypts it, and feeds the decrypted wav file as a memory stream to the player, which plays the wav file normally.

I tried this with NAudio, (with code taken from this question: [Play audio from a stream using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184683/play-audio-from-a-stream-using-c-sharp/225244#225244)) but the code throws an exception saying that the cryptoStream does not support seeking, so it fails trying to create the blockAlignedStream.

```
public void PlayEncMP3(String sourceFile)
{
    //FileInfo info = new FileInfo(sourceFile);
    FileStream input = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("64BITKEY");
    cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("64BIT_IV");

    CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(input, cryptic.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    using (WaveStream blockAlignedStream =
        new BlockAlignReductionStream(
            WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(
                new Mp3FileReader(crStream))))
    {
        using (WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback()))
        {
            waveOut.Init(blockAlignedStream);
            waveOut.Play();
            while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to get this working?

Edit: I tried eliminating the block aligned stream entirely and just using the cryptoStream (instead of the blockAlignedStream) in the waveOut.Init, but it can't convert the cryptoStream to the NAudio.Wave.IWaveProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use Mp3FileReader without a seekable stream because it tries to build a table of contents first, and it also supports repositioning during playback. So you'd need to read the entire MP3 into a memory stream first, then give that to Mp3FileReader.

Comment: Okay, I modified the code to convert the cryptostream to a memorystream, and that worked... the mp3 plays the sound. However, the while loop aftger the play never exits... the PlaybackState is never getting changed from Playing. Removing the while loop results in the sound not playing at all. Any ideas?