# NAudio Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, naudio

Referring to this question, I have used the code from it: [Play audio from a stream using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184683/play-audio-from-a-stream-using-c-sharp)

However, I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" running in debug. I have assigned Url's to a combo box, and when I choose the first choice, opening an ASX stream, the program crashes, giving me the above in debugger.

Any ideas? I have tried doing some fixing with the code below, but I don't think I'm getting the idea, since it still isn't working.

Edit:// It doesn't recognize Mp3FileReader however there are no errors/warnings, it isn't green as it normally would be, am I missing a library?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio;

    public static void PlayMp3FromUrl(string url)
    {
        using (Stream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (Stream stream = WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
                int read;
                while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }

            ms.Position = 0;

            Mp3FileReader fr = new Mp3FileReader(ms);
            WaveStream blockAlignedStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(fr));

            if(ms != null)
            {
                using (WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback()))
                {
                    waveOut.Init(blockAlignedStream);
                    waveOut.Play();
                    while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("blockAlignedStream variable was null!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What line is the exception on?

Comment: `Mp3FileReader fr = new Mp3FileReader(ms);` I took it out from the line below, but it still throws the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code sample you are using is not a good example of how to play an MP3 from a stream. There are multiple problems with the code. Either use the technique described in [this article](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/how-to-play-back-streaming-mp3-using.html), or you may be able to make use of the new `MediaFoundationReader` which can play from a URL.