# C# function to play base64 encoded mp3 file

Tags: c#, audio, base64, mp3, .net-4.5

I am trying to create a function `PlaySoud` that accepts a mp3 file as base64 encoded string and plays it using `System.Media.SoundPlayer`.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var audioBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"PATH-TO-FILE");
        var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(audioBytes);
        PlaySoud(base64String);
    }

    static void PlaySoud(string base64String)
    {
        var audioBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(audioBuffer))
        {
            var player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(ms);
            player.Play();
        }
    }
```

I am currently running into an exception on line `player.Play()` stating `The wave header is corrupt` with stack trace

`at System.Media.SoundPlayer.ValidateSoundData(Byte[] data)
   at System.Media.SoundPlayer.LoadAndPlay(Int32 flags)
   at System.Media.SoundPlayer.Play()
   at POC.Program.PlaySoud(String base64String) in c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\POC\POC\Program.cs:line 21
   at POC.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\POC\POC\Program.cs:line 12
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()`

Most of the MSDN discussions on this error were pointing to resetting the stream position to `0`, but it did not help.

Could you please let me know what is wrong with the `PlaySound` function? Is there an issue in the way I am encoding or decoding the mp3 file?

Comment: There is nothing immediately wrong with your code - most likely "The wave header is corrupt" - in a sense of you playing non -WAV file (i.e. MP3). If you actually trying to play MP3 (which seem to be the case based on your post) it is very strange that you trying to use `SoundPlayer` when all articles that can be found https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+play+mp3 suggest otherwise.

Comment: it's no problem with encoding/decoding. The `SoundPlayer` class only accepts .wav files

Comment: My bad! I was indeed trying to play `*.mp3` file using `SoundPlayer`... :(

Answer (score 2):

The `SoundPlayer` class can only play .wav files. - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can use the WindowsMediaPlayer in your app to play .mp3 files as well as many other formats. Just add the correct references and you are good to go. [(Help)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564585(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
wplayer.URL = "My MP3 file.mp3";
wplayer.controls.play();
```

**Update:** If you need to play your mp3 from a stream, see [Play audio from a stream using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184683/play-audio-from-a-stream-using-c-sharp). Alternatively you can also create a temporary file and play that.

Comment: But would `WMPLib` support playing from a stream (I don't think so)? I actually want to play a `base64` encoded mp3 file?