# Unable to play a mp3 file from clipboard

Tags: vb.net, memory, mp3, clipboard

I have this small project in VB NET that should play a mp3 file from the clipboard using AxWindowsMediaPlayer1. The code is working up to the last line, where I'd want to play the mp3 (just decrypted) bytes that are in memory instead of saving them into a file and then play the file.

Here's the code. The Form needs 3 Buttons, 1 Label, 1 Windows Media Player. You should choose one mp3 file of yours. Hope that somebody can help me!

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    End
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rijndael As New RijndaelManaged()
    rijndael.KeySize = 256
    rijndael.BlockSize = 256
    rijndael.IV = New [Byte]() {24, 23, 35, 83, 77, 35, 28, 34, 94, 25, 45, 2, 73, 26, 27, 78, 12, 23, 35, 83, 57, 35, 28, 34, 94, 25, 45, 22, 73, 26, 27, 78}
    Dim password As Byte() = New Byte(31) {}
    UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("123abc").CopyTo(password, 0)
    Dim file_to_read As New CryptoStream(File.OpenRead("C:\Users\User\Desktop\aa.mp3"),
  rijndael.CreateEncryptor(password, rijndael.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
    Dim file_to_write As Stream = File.OpenWrite("C:\Users\User\Desktop\bb.mp3")
    file_to_read.CopyTo(file_to_write)
    file_to_write.Flush()
    file_to_write.Close()
    file_to_read.Close()
    Label1.Text = "Crypted!"
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim rijndael As New RijndaelManaged()
    rijndael.KeySize = 256
    rijndael.BlockSize = 256
    rijndael.IV = New [Byte]() {24, 23, 35, 83, 77, 35, 28, 34, 94, 25, 45, 2, 73, 26, 27, 78, 12, 23, 35, 83, 57, 35, 28, 34, 94, 25, 45, 22, 73, 26, 27, 78}
    Dim password As Byte() = New Byte(31) {}
    UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("123abc").CopyTo(password, 0)
    Dim mp3Bytes() As Byte
    Using file_to_read As New CryptoStream(File.OpenRead("C:\Users\User\Desktop\bb.mp3"), rijndael.CreateDecryptor(password, rijndael.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
        Using memory_stream As New MemoryStream
            file_to_read.CopyTo(memory_stream)
            mp3Bytes = memory_stream.GetBuffer
        End Using
    End Using
    Label1.Text = "Decrypted!"

    Clipboard.Clear()            'clear the clipboard
    Clipboard.SetAudio(mp3Bytes) 'set the mp3 audio file bytes to the clipboard
    If Clipboard.ContainsAudio Then
        Dim bytes_from_clipboard() As Byte = {}
        Using clipboard_stream As Stream = Clipboard.GetAudioStream
            ReDim bytes_from_clipboard(CInt(clipboard_stream.Length) - 1)
            clipboard_stream.Read(bytes_from_clipboard, 0, CInt(clipboard_stream.Length))
        End Using

        'UP TO THIS POINT IT IS OKAY. FROM HERE THE FREELANCER'S TASK BEGINS
        'I would like to play with Windows Media Player the mp3 file just decrypted into the clipboard.

        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play() ' ???? WHAT CAN I DO HERE? IS THERE ANY SOLUTION?

    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: AxWindowsMediaPlayer doesn't know what's in the clipboard. if you don't want to save it to a file and only have a stream, maybe you can try the NAudio library to play the mp3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184683/play-audio-from-a-stream-using-c-sharp

Comment: I love the code comment "UP TO THIS POINT IT IS OKAY. FROM HERE THE FREELANCER'S TASK BEGINS".

Answer (score 0):

AxWindowsMediaPlayer does not have a source that's why it is not playing. You should use:

```
AxWindowsMediaPlayer.URL = 'location/source of the mp3 file
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
```

Hope that helps!