# How to convert a byte array into WaveStream in NAudio?

Tags: c#, naudio, wave

I want to convert a byte array (read from mp3 file) into a WaveStream, then create a WaveChannel32 to play audio in NAudio. I can read byte array to Stream, then to Mp3FileReader but it does not allow me to change volume. So I have to use WaveChannel32 instead.

Comment: There is a similar post- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184683/play-audio-from-a-stream-using-c-sharp not sure if it can solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `Mp3FileReader` to the `WaveChannel32` which will allow you to pan and change volume.

```
var mp3Bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("d:/Music/RICHARD JOSEPH - Gods17.mp3");
using (var mp3Stream = new MemoryStream(mp3Bytes))
{
    using (var mp3FileReader = new Mp3FileReader(mp3Stream))
    {
        using (var wave32 = new WaveChannel32(mp3FileReader, 0.1f, 1f))
        {
            using (var ds = new DirectSoundOut())
            {
                ds.Init(wave32);
                ds.Play();
                Thread.Sleep(30000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matias. This is the answer I need.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend just using the `AudioFileReader` class as that provides volume for you and uses an `Mp3FileReader` under the hood for MP3s.

Comment: I have a question for you. how can i create an mp3 file from bytes array? i have converted a file into bytes using ReadAllBytes(file); in c#. please help.

Comment: and please let me know if you can help me in changing the channels mono/stereo while converting file type from .wav to .mp3.... i am using LAME.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var ms = new MemoryStream(soundArray.ToArray());
            IWaveProvider provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(ms, new WaveFormat());
            var waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOut();
            waveOut.DeviceNumber = GetDeviceNumber();
            waveOut.Init(provider);
            waveOut.Play();
```