# How can I play an audio stream from web request?

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, naudio

I want to play an audio stream from web request.

I send the request to TTS API Url and then received the result stream.

How can I play it without saving it in my disk.

Comment: Answer already exists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184683/play-audio-from-a-stream-using-c-sharp Or is soemthing not right with that example? By design all Streams are interchangeable and can encapsulate one another. The only real problem is finding a GUI element that can work with incomplete Audio Streams.