# SoundPlayer crash while reading data from MemoryStream

Tags: c#, audio, console-application

I'm making a small application that receive data from another application and play the sound it receives parts by parts.

This is the simulation I'm doing:

```
        var soundPlayer = new  SoundPlayer();
        var buffer = new byte[2048];
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            var iOffset = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    iOffset = fileStream.Read(buffer, iOffset, buffer.Length);
                    if (iOffset == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Offset end.");
                        break;
                    }

                    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    soundPlayer.Stream = memoryStream;
                    //soundPlayer.Load();
                    soundPlayer.Play();

                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

It reads a file to memory stream parts by parts (2048 bytes per 5 seconds - connection delay simulation)

The application crashes without jumping into exception code block after `soundPlayer.Play()` method.

What wrong am I doing ?

Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the exception thrown?

Comment: It crashed without jumping into exception

Comment: Probably because you're not reading the entire file. When I run your code it gives that it tried to read or write in a protected memory. The wav header has a field that indicates the chunk size in bytes, so the player probably tries to read that amout of bytes, which is bigger than the stream size.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can not use the `SoundPlayer` in that way. From the [documentation of the SoundPlayer class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?view=netframework-4.7.1):

> A SoundPlayer configured to load a .wav file from a Stream or URL must
>   load the .wav file into memory before playback begins.

If you want to be able to receive an audio stream in chunks you need to use another library. I can recommend [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio). See also this SO post [Play audio from a stream using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184683/play-audio-from-a-stream-using-c-sharp).