# Redirecting an Audio Stream to avoid CORS - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, audio, cross-domain, audiocontext

I need to redirect an audio stream to avoid CORS in order to use AudioContext() for visualizations.

Instead of using the original stream url, I'd point the player to "mysite.com/stream/", which would intercept the stream and feed it to the player.

I really don't know what I'm doing in this case, which should be obvious from my attempt below. Thanks to anyone for some help.

```
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest web = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://ssl.geckohost.nz/proxy/caitlinssl?mp=/stream");

Response.ContentType = "audio/aac";

char[] buffer = new char[8192];
byte[] buffer_bytes = new byte[8192];

using (System.Net.HttpWebResponse web_resp = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)web.GetResponse())
{
    using (System.IO.Stream stream_web = web_resp.GetResponseStream())
    {
        //stream_web.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);

        using (System.IO.StreamReader stream_rdr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream_web))
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                stream_rdr.Read(buffer, 0, 8192);

                Response.Write(buffer);
                Response.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was originally created for use with NAudio to play a remote MP3 file, but I was able to repurpose it for my needs. There are probably better ways, but this works.

[Play audio from a stream using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184683/play-audio-from-a-stream-using-c-sharp)

Edit: It seems that the connection is dropped server to server, but I'm not positive. IIS will not send "Connection: keep-alive" to the client, however it is being sent to the client by the original stream. Tried adding KeepAlive = true to the WebRequest, and changing the protocol version to HTTP 1.0 to keep the server to server connection alive with no joy.

```
string url = "https://ssl.geckohost.nz/proxy/caitlinssl?mp=/stream";

Response.ContentType = "audio/aac";

using (Stream stream = WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
    int read;
    while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        Response.Flush();
    }        
}
```

Conclusion: It seems that in this case it is not possible with IIS to persist the connection server to server, as far as I was able to find. I'm not worried about scalability as this is a personal project for a user of 1. The solution I ended up with is to start capturing the stream with ffmpeg on click, transcode it to flac/mkv, and use a variation of the above to read the file while it's being written and feed it to the player (WPF WebView [IE/Edge]).

Comment: Note: While this works, it only streams about 1 MB of data or for about 2 minutes. :(