# Playing audio from buffer in C# in Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, audio

I'm doing programm, that will generate sin waves. I can save them in file and after play them, but i don't now how to play them from buffer.

Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play audio from a stream using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184683/play-audio-from-a-stream-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @E_net4-MrDownvoter: will that work on linux?

Comment: @Stefan At least [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) claims to support Linux, so long as the Windows-specific modules are excluded.

Comment: NAudio relies on API calls to DirectSound, WaveIn/WaveOut, and other dependencies that do not run on linux.